# Log4j - How to print all classes/methods

Tags: java, log4j

I'm new to log4j, and only an occasional Java coder. I have a fairly large Java application for which I need to make a plugin (to customize a part of the interface), and there is only some generic documentation available on how to do it, which doesn't help me much. I can inspect the application source for clues, using a decompiler, but it is huge, so is there any way to configure log4j to print out all of the class/method names as they are called, so that I can see what classes/methods are responsibe for particular actions in the interface?

Thanks in advance,

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, modify your [log4j pattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) to include the fully qualified class name in the log message by adding `%C` and method name with `%M`. You'll end up with a pattern similar to `"%d %-5p [%C] %M: %m%n`. Please be aware that the javadoc also states that

> **WARNING** Generating caller location information is extremely slow and
>   should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Comment: Guess you wanted to say `%M: %m` (and not `%m: %m`). 

Also, the logger has to be called at least one time in each method to show each method call.

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat. Not all of the methods call the logger, but it's given me a good starting point.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be even somewhat helpful